# Getting date in CSS and HTML to PDF's footer

Tags: html, css, pdf

Im using ITextRenderer to generate a pdf file from html and css, I have a footer with the current page on the right.

But now i would like to have the current date on the left.

I found this:

```
<div data-line="1"></div>

div[data-line]:after { 
  content: "[line " attr(data-line) "]"; 
}
```

But I dont know how to combine it with :

```
@bottom-left {
  content: "Date: ";
}
```

Is this possible or is there any other way?

I would like the footer to look something like this: 
Date: 2015-03-17  12:04

UPDATE 1:

I have a method createPDF(string html, String resourceUrl), that looks like this:

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
  TagNode node = cleaner.clean(html);

  CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();
  new SimpleXmlSerializer(props).writeToStream(node, out, "ISO-8859-1");

  ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
  renderer.setPDFVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7);

  renderer.setDocumentFromString(new String(out.toByteArray(), "ISO-8859-1"));
  renderer.getSharedContext().setBaseURL(resourceUrl);

  renderer.layout();

  ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
  renderer.finishPDF();

  outputStream.flush();
  outputStream.close();

  return outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [example](http://davidwalsh.name/css-content-attr) that you cite of using `data-line` in the CSS is an interesting way to dynamically generate CSS based on data-* HTML attributes. These in turn might be dynamically generated in a web page by a server-side or client-side script. But it seems like this might not be the appropriate method for your case.

If you are already using a Java class like ITextRenderer to generate this PDF, then the best method for you is probably just to use Java itself to generate the current date in the format that you want, then print that directly into the CSS as a string.

If you are loading the CSS from a manually created file, one way to do this would be to write your CSS with some text you intend to replace, for example `INSERTDATE`. Then in Java, load your document the way you normally do, then use some Java code like String.replace() to replace `INSERTDATE` with today's date.

**Update 1:**

Based on your sample code above, you could write `INSERTDATE` where you want the date to appear in your HTML/CSS, then call:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"); # your desired format
String strDate = sdf.format(new Date()); # get the current date
html = html.replace("INSERTDATE", strDate);
```

at the top of your method.

Comment: Okey, and how would I print it directly into the CSS? Could you explain or do you know of any good example ?   I dont use ITextRenderer  to generate the CSS, i create the CSS myself, its the PDF the ITextRenderer generates for me from my HTML and CSS code.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I've edited my answer above. If you want something that's more specific, it might be helpful if you could paste the Java code you use for loading your files into ITextRenderer into your original question.

Comment: Okey, so I updated my original question to make it more clear. The string html in both the html and css content. It is all i want to show on the pages.

Comment: Ok great, that's pretty straightforward then. Try to see if something like the above edit works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `string-set` with `content()` and `string()` css functions , see https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/ like :

```
<div class="where-content-comes-from">1</div>
<div class="where-content-is-injected"></div>

.where-content-comes-from{
    display:none;
    string-set: am-just-a-var content();
}   
.where-content-is-injected:after { 
  content: string(am-just-a-var);
}
```

bonus : you can also use css `env()` function to display date value see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env